# Check if uri is already in arraylist<uri>

Tags: android, listview, uri

I'm attaching image uri's on my ListView. I can attach same uri's like this one:

[image]

What I want to do, is set a condition that if that image uri is already on that listview, I'll not be able to attach it like the one above (same uri). I'm thinking of setting an if and else condition before the array_list.add(uri); But I don't know what condition can be set on checking if the image uri already exist on the listview.

How can I do that? Thanks.

```
ListView lv;
ArrayList<Uri> array_list = new ArrayList<Uri>();
ArrayAdapter<Uri> array_adapter;

final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;

onCreate ...

Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);

array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(array_adapter);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_LOADIMAGE);                          
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == RQS_LOADIMAGE) {

          if(resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            array_list.add(uri);
            array_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `"uri already in arraylist<uri>" == "arraylist<uri> contains uri"` now check documentation of ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` has a method, `contains()`, which checks that if object exists or not. So, as per your requirement,

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

if (!array_list.contains(uri))
  array_list.add(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be:

```
if (!your_array_list.contains(uri_text))
  your_array_list.add(uri_text);
```

So you're checking prior to adding and item whether there is already an URI with that text.

Comment: uri_text? You mean Uri uri_text = data.getData();?

Comment: I was using a generic name; in your case it would be just `uri`